# Parent UITableViewController not rendering when child rotates

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

The app I am building is having some issues when navigating in landscape mode.
This is how the table looks in portrait [image: The navigation looks great in portrait and if I rotate to landscape on this screen]
but if I go to one of the child navigation items rotate and then navigate back in landscape it looks like this
[image: EEEWWWW] 
I have tried everything I can think of and cannot fix it, I am using auto layout and storyboards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the table view isn't the main view of the view controller (i.e., `self.view`). Perhaps you dragged a table view from the object library onto the canvas for your view controller's storyboard scene. When you do that, the default implicit constraints created by Xcode will produce the situation you described upon rotation. You need to create your own *explicit* constraints in the storyboard that pin the four sides of the table view to its superview.

Comment: This is what I had ended up doing but I wasn't able to define constraints for the table view for some reason. But I rebuilt the view to have the table view sitting inside a regular UIViewController and was able to set those constraints and it worked!! Thanks